# Weird failed assertion with mocha/chai and ES6 Promise

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, es6-promise

I faced a strange behavior with ES6 Promise and some mocha/chai tests.
Considering the following `foo()` function that returns a promise, I want to test two things:

- it returns a promise (and so, an object)
- it throws an exception (and so, an object) on failure.

Problem is, following test `expect(..).to.be.an('object')` fails in both case, but the type **is** `object` (checked with `typeof`).

Here is my code:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;

var foo = function (a, b) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (a < b) {
      resolve();
    }
    else {
      throw new Error('failed');
    }
  });
}

describe('foo function', function () {
  it('should return a promise', function () {
    var call = foo();

    //typeof call: object
    expect(call).to.be.defined; //pass
    expect(call).to.be.an('object'); //fail
    expect(call.then).to.be.a('function'); //pass
  });

  it('should throw an exception on failure', function () {
    return foo().catch(function (e) {

      //typeof e: object
      expect(e).to.be.defined; //pass
      expect(e).to.be.an('object'); //fail
    });
  })
});
```

Do you have any clue to explain this?

If it can helps, here is the result of the mocha call `mocha test.js`

```
foo function
  1) should return a promise
  2) should throw an exception on failure


0 passing (20ms)
2 failing

1) foo function should return a promise:
   AssertionError: expected {} to be an object
    at Context.<anonymous> (test.js:34:24)

2) foo function should throw an exception on failure:
   AssertionError: expected [Error: failed] to be an object
    at test.js:42:23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chai uses [`type-detect`](https://github.com/chaijs/type-detect) for `a/an`, which is smart (depending on how you look at it) in typing objects.

For example:

```
var type    = require('type-detect');
var promise = new Promise(() => {});

console.log( type(promise) ) // 'promise'
```

So this would make your tests pass:

```
expect(call).to.be.a('promise');
...
expect(e).to.be.an('error');
...
```

Either that, or use [`.instanceOf()`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#-instanceof-constructor-):

```
expect(call).to.be.an.instanceOf(Object);
...
expect(e).to.be.an.instanceOf(Error);
...
```

Comment: Indeed it works far better now! It's a shame it doesn't have a sort of inheritance system like "a promise is an object"... Thanks for your answer!